# sqlalchemy how to map a session query result to a defined class object?

Tags: python

I have a class defined like this:

`class InvestedCompany(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'investedcompany'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    investor_id = column(String, ForeignKey('investments.investor_id'))
    investor = relationship(
        Investments,
        backref=backref('investments',
                        uselist=True,
                        cascade='delete,all'))`

I want to conduct a query and map the session.query result to this class.
Something like session.query(company.id, company.name, Investments).filter...

Thank you !